# Listview to SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox, android-listview

I have created a listview which displays the installed applications. It has app icon + app name + check box. I want to select apps from this list and store the app names in a sqlite DB how should I begin with this?

Like how to identify the selected apps?

Comment: some ppl have said you need a column for every list attribute, however what I try to achieve is select applications and store those selected apps in DB. Any ideas ppl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an adapter I made for one of my apps.  This is a classroom attendance function that shows the student's name, photo and a couple of checkboxes (one for here, for for late). The list comes from a SQlite query, but I need to do something with each checkbox that is clicked.

```
public class MyDataAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private Cursor c;
    private Context context;
    private Long classnum;
    private gradeBookDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    public static final int LATE=2;
    public static final int ATTEND=1;
    int idxCol;
    int idx;

    // itemChecked will store the position of the checked items.

    public MyDataAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
            int[] to, Long mRowId) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.c = c;
        this.context = context;
        mDbHelper = new gradeBookDbAdapter(context);
        mDbHelper.open();
        classnum = mRowId;
        c.moveToFirst();



    }
    public class ViewHolder{
        public TextView text;
        public TextView text2;
        public ImageView image;
        public CheckBox here;
        public CheckBox late;
    }


    public View getView(final int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Bitmap bm;
        ImageView studentPhoto;
        View vi=inView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (inView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_attendance, null);

            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.stuname);
            holder.text2=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.stuIndex);
            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.here=(CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.attend);
            holder.late=(CheckBox)vi.findViewById(R.id.late);
            vi.setTag(holder);

        }
        else
           holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();


        c.moveToPosition(pos);
        int index = c.getColumnIndex(gradeBookDbAdapter.KEY_NAME);
        String name = c.getString(index);
        holder.text.setText(name);
        index = c.getColumnIndex(gradeBookDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID); 
        String Index = c.getString(index);
        holder.text2.setText(Index);

        bm = gradeBookDbAdapter.getStudentPhoto(name);
        if (bm != null) {
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(bm);  
        }           
        else {
            // use icon image
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.person_icon);
        }


        // pull out existing attend/late fields and set accordingly
        int attend = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(gradeBookDbAdapter.KEY_ATTEND));
        if(attend==1){
           holder.here.setChecked(true);
           itemCheckedHere.set(pos, true);
        }
        //else {
        //   holder.here.setChecked(false);
        //   itemCheckedHere.set(pos, false);
        //}

        int late = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(gradeBookDbAdapter.KEY_LATE));
        if (late==1){
           holder.late.setChecked(true);
           itemCheckedLate.set(pos, true);
        }
        //else {
        //  holder.late.setChecked(false);
        //    itemCheckedLate.set(pos, false);
        //}




        holder.here.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.attend);

                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                    itemCheckedHere.set(pos, true); 
                    int Index = new Integer(holder.text2.getText().toString());
                    mDbHelper.updateAttend(Index, classnum, ATTEND, 1, attendDate ); 
                } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                    itemCheckedHere.set(pos, false);
                    int Index = new Integer(holder.text2.getText().toString());
                    mDbHelper.updateAttend(Index, classnum, ATTEND, 0, attendDate );
                }
            }
        });
        holder.late.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.late);

                if (cb.isChecked()) {
                   itemCheckedLate.set(pos, true);
                   int Index = new Integer(holder.text2.getText().toString());
                   mDbHelper.updateAttend(Index, classnum, LATE, 1, attendDate );
                } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                   itemCheckedLate.set(pos, false);
                   int Index = new Integer(holder.text2.getText().toString());
                   mDbHelper.updateAttend(Index, classnum, LATE, 0, attendDate );
                }
            }
        });


        holder.here.setChecked(itemCheckedHere.get(pos)); // this will Check or Uncheck the
        holder.late.setChecked(itemCheckedLate.get(pos)); // this will Check or Uncheck the
        // CheckBox in ListView
        // according to their original
        // position and CheckBox never
        // loss his State when you
        // Scroll the List Items.

        return vi;
    }

}
```

Notice I have two sparse arrays "ItemCheckedHere' and "ItemCheckLate". these keep track of which items I've selected. Android doesn't keep track and will reuse a view, so scrolling a list of checkboxes will result in boxes getting checked or unchecked seemingly at random without these arrays I use to maintain the checked status.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to make a custom listView adapter. You can make each item selectable and then when the user selects an app, you can call the code to insert it into your DB

Comment: so it means on each select unselect DB add/remove to be called? I have a custom listview adapter how to write the onclicklistner for the check box? any example..